# Text input from jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a script that appends  a set of constant string to a `textarea` it works fine if I click the button first but as soon as I input text on the textarea, the button does not append the constant string on the textarea if clicked again

here is my code for the click event:

```
    $("#apply").on("click",function() {
        var  orange = $("#agent_option").val(),
          lock = $("#agent_disallowed").val();

        $("#textareaFixed").html(orange + " " + lock );
    });
```

and Here is my html form:

```
<label for="agent_option" class="control-label">User-Agent :</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
             <select id="agent_option" class="form-control input-sm">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="banana">Banana</option>
                <option value="apple">Apple</option>
                <option value="melon">Melon</option>
                <option value="lynx">Lynx</option>
                <option value="liger">Liger</option>
             </select>
            </div>
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="ax_disallowed" class="control-label">Disallow :</label></div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                 <input class="form-control input-sm" id="ax_disallowed" type="text" value="<?=ax_default_disallow;?>">
                </div>
            </div>

   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="apply" class="btn btn-default">Register Player</button>
   </div>
```

This is my textarea:

```
<form  method="post" class="form-login">
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="new_config" class="form-control" id="textareaFixed" cols="60" rows="16"><?=file_get_contents($open); ?></textarea>
              </div>

            </form>
```

please help me I tried google it but found irrelevant results. you guys are my only hope now :(

Comment: Please explain: analysis of your code shows that clicking the button simply overrides and destroys any text within textarea. Is that right?

Comment: yes sir it overrides any text inside the textarea

Comment: So where is the problem if it overrides? What is your goal? To append instead of overriding?

Comment: My concern is that if a user types something on the textarea the button should still work but thats not the case it doesnt work anymore.. but if I refresh the page and click the button 1st it works but if I edit again the textarea and click the button again it wont work again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.html(...)` to `.val(...)`

```
$("#apply").on("click",function() {
    var orange = $("#agent_option").val(),
        lock = $("#ax_disallowed").val();

    $("#textareaFixed").val(orange + " " + lock );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `append()` instead of `html()`

Please try `$("#textareaFixed").append(orange + " " + lock );` if you want to add the new text after the previous one.

If you use `html()`, it replaces the old stuff with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any input named as "agent_disallowed", you need to use correct id.

```
 $("#apply").on("click",function() {
     var  orange = $("#agent_option").val();
     var  lock = $("#ax_disallowed").val();
     $("#textareaFixed").html(orange + " " + lock );
 });
```

Comment: sorry Its still the same.. @bowheart's answer did the trick thanks for the response though :)